minimization weakly lower semicontinuous functional on unitary ball boundary
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a disk. Assume $J:L^2(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}^+$ is a weakly-$L^2$ lower semi continuous functional, coercive on $L^2(\Omega)$ (we can even assume $M \mapsto J(M)$ quadratic).
I want to study the existence of solutions of the following minimization problem
$$ \min \{J(M), \ || M||_{L^2(\Omega)} = 1\}. $$
As far I understood, the constraint $|| M||_{L^2(\Omega)} = 1$ is not continuous w.r.t. the weak-$L^2$ topology (the norm is just lower semicontinuous w.r.t. such topology), so that relaxation is needed.
First of all, is this true? Is the relaxation known, at least in some cases?
Some elucidation would be well accepted. Thanks

Such a problem has no solution in general. An example would be
$$
J(u) := \int_0^1 (1 + x) u(x)^2 \ dx.
$$
The infimum is equal to $1$ (take $u_n := \chi_{(0,\frac1n)} \sqrt n$), but is is not attained.
The problem for quadratic $J$  is equivalent to an eigenvalue problem: If $J(u) = \langle Au,u\rangle$ with bounded and self-adjoint $A$, then solutions of the minimization problem are eigenvectors of $A$.
There are several possible relaxations: changing the feasible set to $\{u: \ \|u\|_{L^2} \le 1\}$, adding something like $\epsilon \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2$ to $J$, Young-measure relaxation etc. Not sure what you are after.

I had in mind $\min{ \int_{\Omega} |E(u)|^2 dx,  \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 dx = 1, u \in H_0^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^n) }$, where $E(u)$ is the symmetric part of $\nabla u$. The result is the so called Korn constant. However, I cannot prove the existence of such minimization problem via the direct method. In my case if I set the constraint  $\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 dx \leq 1$ the min is zero. I'd like the $\inf { \liminf J(M_n), || M_n||_{L^2} = 1, M_n \to M \  weakly \ L^2}$

Such problems result in eigenvalue problems. Then one has to think about the smallest eigenvalue of the corresponding operator.
